# Why postgresql trigger doesn't launch?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I use postgresql 11.
I think my problem comes from a trigger that doesn't do an update so the next trigger doesn't launch.

I have a table `projet` with columns : `projet_temps_doe`, `projet_temps_etudes`, `projet_temps_globale`.

The goal is to update each columns depending on other columns values.
The idea is : `projet_temps_globale` = `projet_temps_doe` + `projet_temps_etudes`.

I have a first trigger on `projet_temps_doe` which works perfectly:

```sql
create function temps_globale_doe() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
        new.projet_temps_globale_doe :=  new.projet_temps_doe_gc_bts + new.projet_temps_doe_gc_nra;
        return new;
    end;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER temps_globale_doe
    BEFORE UPDATE OF projet_temps_doe_gc_bts, projet_temps_doe_gc_nra
    ON public.projet
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.temps_globale_doe();
```

I have a similar trigger on `projet_temps_etudes` which works perfectly too.

Then the trigger I struggle with on `projet_temps_globale` :

```sql
create trigger maj_temps_globale_projet
    before update of projet_temps_doe, projet_temps_etudes on projet
    for each row
    execute procedure maj_temps_globale_projet();

create or replace function maj_temps_globale_projet()returns trigger
language plpgsql
as
    $$
    begin
        new.projet_temps_globale := new.projet_temps_doe + new.projet_temps_etudes;
        raise info 'TEST!!';
        return new;
    end;
    $$;
```

When `projet_temps_doe` and/or `projet_temps_etudes` are updated via triggers my last trigger doesn't launch. However when I manually change `projet_temps_doe` and/or `projet_temps_etudes` values the trigger maj_temps_globale_projet is fired.

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) says

> The trigger will only fire if at least one of the listed columns is
>   mentioned as a target of the UPDATE command.

The column `projet_temps_globale_doe` is not part of the update command but is rather set in another trigger via `new.projet_temps_globale_doe = ...` so the trigger on this particular column is not called.

It would be easier to have only one trigger on the entire table that sets the 3 derived values.

Comment: That's right, I tride with only one trigger for the 3 derived values and it works perfectly. Thank you